# Can we use SWIG to make python bindings for Qt application?

Tags: python, c++, qt, swig

How to use SWIG to binding to QT application, our situation is almost the same as the situation in this [post](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/pyside/2013-January/000957.html), which says:

> - We have a big C++/Qt application with a Swig binding of the core.
> - We wanted to create new UI tools in python which need to use some of
>     our C++ widgets. So we need a binding of our C++ widgets. As our core
>     binding is written in Swig (and we are happy with that) we need to bind our
>     widgets with the same binding tool for compatibility.

Seems they had successfully created binding of Qt in SWIG, but there seems not easy to wrap QT using swig because QT application with macro Q_OBJECT will generate moc files at precompile time and at compile time these files are used. I tried this:

```
>> swig -c++ -python application.i
application.h:46: Error: Syntax error in input(3)
```

it always give error about line 46 which indicate to Q_OBJECT.

I also found [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/swig/mailman/message/30818925/) and [here](https://github.com/swig/swig/issues/88#issuecomment-202054188) saying that it's impossible to use swig to wrap QT, I am so confused about this, can someone show some light about this if it is not feasible or if it can, give a simple example about using SWIG wrap QT. Thanks in advance.

**Update** source file: application.h

```
#ifndef   APPLICATION_H_
#define   APPLICATION_H_

#include <QApplication>

class frameApplication : public QApplication
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    frameApplication (){};
    virtual ~frameApplication();

private slots:
    void OnExitApp();

};
#endif  // APPLICATION_H_
```

application.i

```
%module application
%{
#include "application.h"
%}
%include "application.h"
```

This is a simplified version of application.h, using above SWIG command, the error message remains the same except the line number.

Comment: yes, not just Q_OBJECT, but also Q_SINGAL/Q_SLOTS etc.

Comment: That's why swig cannot handle QT application, quote from one of the above link: "I'm not sure if there is a full list of Qt's macros but here are quite a few. All of their concepts can me expressed through C++ and this is what they do internally. They have a tool called moc (Meta-Object Compiler) that is run on their code before any other steps. It produces standard C++ which is then compiled. The problem is that it produces only "real" cpp files, not "real" headers, and, as stated in the documentation, SWIG cannot be relied upon to work properly with C++ source files."

Comment: Sigh, if the C++ compiler **itself** can handle these files, SWIG can handle them too. I've done it plenty of times. It works fine. They are valid C++ sources for crying out loud, what kind of magic does one have to believe in to think otherwise! Repeat after me: **a .cpp/.h file that has Qt macros is passed unchanged to the C++ compiler and is valid C++**. That's the whole **point** of a C++ framework. The only think that moc does is to generate a few member definitions (not declarations!) and some static data - none of that is needed by Swig, or by the compiler.

Comment: I  think swig do not need dependence to generate wrap file. Only when we compile the swig generated wrap file into .o file then we need specify dependence. If anybody have QT env, please just have a  try.

Comment: As I've said: it works when you give proper arguments to SWIG. Swig *does* need dependencies because it need to correctly preprocess the file! Come on: it fails for you **specifically** because you didn't let it know what `Q_OBJECT` is. You know that. "I think swig do not need dependence to generate wrap file." You can't think that, given the very question of yours.

Answer (score 5):

> Can we use SWIG to make python bindings for Qt application?

**YES**!

The error happens because your header file uses macros that SWIG doesn't know about. A C++ compiler wouldn't know about them either, of course.

SWIG needs to preprocess your input. To do that, it needs to know *both* the include paths to Qt, and the defines needed for Qt headers to work.

On my particular project using the Widgets package, on an OSX Qt install, SWIG would need the following arguments, for example:

```
-DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB \
-I/Qt/5.6.0/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers \ 
-I/Qt/5.6.0/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers \ 
-I/Qt/5.6.0/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers \ 
-I/Qt/5.6.0/mkspecs/macx-clang
```

SWIG goes a long way to keep quiet about missing include files. It tries to do its best at parsing the input even when include files are missing, and makes some assumptions about what the various identifiers are even if they are undefined, but it can't do much when presented with unknown macros that don't merely expand to a single identifier.

The easiest way to get the necessary define (`-D`) and include path (`-I`) options is to build your code and get these from the compiler's command line. SWIG *purposefully* uses the same option syntax as most C/C++ compilers - to make passing that data easier.

It should be said that SWIG knows nothing special about signals nor slots: they are just C++ methods. Any bindings generated by SWIG won't support the use of Qt 5's new `connect` syntax to link signals and slots. You can still use the Qt 4 syntax where you pass C string method signatures to `connect`, e.g.:

```
// with SIGNAL/SLOT macros
connect(obj1, SIGNAL(foo(QString)), obj2, SLOT(bar(QString)));
// without SIGNAL/SLOT macros - as you would call from a SWIG binding
connect(obj1, "2foo(QString)\0", obj2, "1bar(QString)\0");
```

The method signature needs to be suffixed by an extra null terminator. Signals are prefixed with `'2'`, slots are prefixed with `'1'`, other invokable methods are prefixed with `'0'`.

You won't be able to define new signals or invokable methods unless you use the private `QMetaObjectBuilder`; see [here](https://www.qtdeveloperdays.com/sites/default/files/QtDevDays2014US-DIY-moc.pdf).